# Android CardView нажатие на элемент

Tags: android

имеется RecyclerView и CardView. Никак не могу найти метод, который отвечает за нажатие item. Хочу чтобы при нажатии на один из элементов, высветилось Диалоговое окно.
Класс адаптер:

```
public class CityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CityAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<City> cities;
    private Context ctx;

    public CityAdapter(List<City> cities, Context ctx) {
        this.cities = cities;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_cities, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CityAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final City city = cities.get(position);
        holder.textViewCity.setText(city.getCity());
        holder.textViewFullCity.setText(city.getFullCity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cities.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewCity;
        public TextView textViewFullCity;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCity);
            textViewFullCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullCity);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте следующий код:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textViewCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCity);
    textViewFullCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullCity);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.getContext());
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    });
}
```

Comment: А можно без лямбда выражений? Выдает ошибку Lambda expresions are not supported at language level '1.7'

Comment: Java 8 установлено

Comment: все, сам исправил

Comment: @danilshik ты моя умничка :3